# Why C++11 implicitly deletes my default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor

I wanted to make my class uncopyable using C++11, before I privately inherited my class from `boost::noncopyable`. In C++11 I implemented following:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
};
```

With this change compilation of a client code (with VS 2013) gives me following error:

```
..\main.cpp(9): error C2512: 'Foo' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

My client code is pretty simple:

```
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

Is there any C++11 rule which implicitly *deletes default constructor* in my case ?

Comment: g++-4.9 says the same. Anyway, it's simple to fix: `Foo() = default;`.

Comment: @stefan But what is C++11 rule which deletes default constructor in my case ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default constructor for `Foo` is not deleted, it is simply not defined. An explicitly defaulted/deleted constructor is a *user-declared* constructor, and this causes an implicit declaration of a default constructor to be inhibited. `Foo` has a *user-declared* constructor, the explicitly deleted copy constructor.

From N3337, *§12.1/5* **[class.ctor]**

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. **If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted** (8.4). `...`

---

Note that if the default constructor was indeed deleted, the error message would probably have said as much. For instance, if I change the definition of `Foo` to

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int &i;
};
```

the presence of the data member of reference type implicitly deletes the default constructor. Now, [clang and gcc produce the error messages](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaa1af70f80dfbdc)

> error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'Foo'

and

> error: use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo()'

Compare these to the error messages produced by your [original example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0698e5c9b16db9a)

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Foo'
>   error: no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'

---

To fix your example, you'll need to explicitly default the default constructor

```
Foo() = default;
```

Answer (score 6):

The implicit default constructor is not deleted, it's just not generated if you have other constructors. This has been the same since very old time.

C++03 [class.ctor]/5:

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a default constructor is implicitly declared.

C++11 [class.ctor]/5 (same in C++14):

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted